# Regex in URL for matching an ID

Tags: c#, regex

i need a regex for something like this(actually the ID(number) between "=" and "&" e.g. "=376629&"):

> http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=376629&part=Borrowing+100%2c000+Arrows

What I found is this:

```
      [^0-9$,]
```

But this will not match this:

> http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=376629&part=Borrowing+100%2c000+Arrows

only this:

> http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=85808&part=Boseiju%2c+Who+Shelters+All

The match would be what I want "85808".

May be you can help me,Thank you.

Comment: if you want `=`,`&` also then use, `=\d+&`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Regex**

```
id=(\d+)
```

first capture contains the result

**Test Strings**

```
http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=376629&part=Borrowing+100%2c000+Arrows
http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=85808&part=Boseiju%2c+Who+Shelters+All
```

**Result**

- MATCH 1

  1. `376629`
- MATCH 2

  1. `85808`

**Demo**

**[Online Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yA5qV1/1)**

**C# Sample**

```
    string hrefValue = "http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=85808&part=Boseiju%2c+Who+Shelters+All";
    string id = Regex.Match(hrefValue, @"id=(\d+)").Groups[1].Value;
```

**[Online C# Demo](http://ideone.com/cTsqFX)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern:

```
(?<==)[0-9]+(?=&)
```

[Explanation](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28%3F%3C%3D%3D%29%5B0-9%5D%2B%28%3F%3D%26%29)

[Demo](http://ideone.com/JqAIOU)

Comment: Sorry I still get a formatexception, when excecute your regex (Regex.Replace(hrefValue, @"(?<==)[0-9]+(?=&)", string.Empty)) ...

Comment: I guess look behinds are not supported

Comment: @user254197 why do you use a replace method?

Comment: I used it like this "Int32.Parse(Regex.Replace(hrefValue, @"[^0-9$,]", string.Empty));", because this gave me my ID, but this seems not to be a good solution ?!(hrefValue is the URL)